# Get date from calendar control asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i get the current date, day, month from the calendar individually on page load function in C# like the following:

day :Friday
date: 13 // just the d, i don't the full format
month: August

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you are using a Calendar control, you should be able to access a property like [`SelectedDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate(v=vs.110).aspx) that would give you a proper `DateTime` object, which you could use to pull the properties that you need :

```
// Get the selected date
var date = YourCalendar.SelectedDate;

// Get the day of week (e.g. Friday)
var dayOfWeek = date.ToString("dddd");
// Get the day of the month (e.g. 19); Use date.ToString("d") if you need a string
var day = date.Day;                        
// Get the full month name (e.g. August)
var month = date.ToString("MMMM");
```